# Can we customize facebook likebox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, facebook-likebox

I am trying to customize the number of feeds and auto scroll functionality in Facebook likebox using below code.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script>(function(d, s, id) {var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if (d.getElementById(id)) return;js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;js.src="//connect.facebook.net/en_IN/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=453991991316939&version=v2.0";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

[image]
I have tried multiple canvas resize methods given in multiple websites but now getting stuck.
Any ideas? how can I customize this or it will be great if someone have already created plugin for this?

Comment: if I remember correctly, fb likebox like this is loaded in an iframe, so there's not much you can do about its appearance, except from the very limited styling options when creating an actual likebox on facebook.

Comment: you can embed it by iframe, xfbml, and html5, and as a link.

Answer (score 1):

```
You need to copy the given below CSS code with Facebook Like Box code and paste it in your page.
You need to changee the url in iframe *************** to your facebook url.

    <style type="text/css">
     .f-bookMain {
        background-color:#E1E1E1; 
        width:320px; 
        border:1px solid #BCBCBC;
        padding:15px 0 15px 15px;
        height:280px;
      }
     .f-bookInnerBlock { 
        overflow:hidden;
         height:280px;
         border:1px solid #aaa;
      }
    </style>

    <div class="f-bookMain">
    <div class="f-bookInnerBlock">

    <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F***************&amp;
    width=300&amp;height=258&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;header=false&amp;stream=false&amp;
    show_border=false" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:300px; height:258px;" 
    allowTransparency="true">
    </iframe>

    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>

You need to changee the url in iframe *************** to your facebook url.
```